# how to add specific interceptor to resource object get() or update() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hateoas

I am currently using angular-hateoas (https://github.com/jmarquis/angular-hateoas). I would like to add specific interceptors to the query() and get() functions of the resource created in HateoasInterface. I have been looking for ways to do it, but not been successful.

I thought it could be done by adding it like this:

```
var someResource = someService.resource('someresource');
someResource.query.interceptors = {
  response: function (data) {
    // do something data
    return data
  },
  responseError: function (error) {
    // do something with error
    return $q.reject(error);
  }
};
```

but that gives me:

```
 TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

I might need to use $decorator, but I have no experience with that, and I have seen no example for adding specific interceptors to specific resource objects.

I don't really want to use `$httpProvider.interceptors`, since I don't want the interceptor to work on all resources.

The only thing I can currently think of, is configuring HateoasInterfaceProvider  with specificly named functions that contain the specific interceptors.

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .config(HateoasInterfaceConfig);

HateoasInterfaceConfig.$inject = ['HateoasInterfaceProvider'];

function HateoasInterfaceConfig(HateoasInterfaceProvider) {
    HateoasInterfaceProvider.setHttpMethods({
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        },
        getSomeResource: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            interceptors: {
                response: someResponseFunc,
                responseError: someErrorFunc
            }
        },
        update: {
            method: 'POST',
        },
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
        querySomeResource: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            interceptors: {
                response: function(data) { 
                    // do something with data
                    return data;
                },
                responseError: function (error) {
                    //do something with error
                    return $q.reject(error);
            }

        }
    });
    HateoasInterfaceProvider.setLinksKey('_links');
}
```

but I prefer not to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

When calling a resource, params and actions can be passed.

So like:

```
someServiceResult.resource('someresource',{},{get: {method: 'GET',...,
    interceptor: { response: responseInterceptorFunc, ...}}})
```

Still not really the preferred solution, but when wrapped in a function in a service, acceptible.

I would like to have a solution that allows changing the interceptor definition for the Resource object created with:

```
someServiceResult.resource('someresource')
```

but I currently don't have time for figuring that out.